# Directive template bound to Service variable not updating

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angular-services, angular-directive

I have a directive that is using inherited scope from its parent controller. That same directive has a template which has a bound variable from the parent controller. In the attached plunker I have 4 cases that demostrate updating a service and watching the directives bound variable update. Case 3 I cannot explain, or understand why it does not work. Ideally, i would like Case 3 to work where if the exposed service variable updates, then the directives bound variable would update as well, unfortunately that is not the case.

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3pj9j2tPPhrdVZUk4wIA)

script.js file :

```
// Code goes here
(function() {
  'user strict'  ;

  //---------------//
  // define module //
  //---------------//
  angular.module('main', []);

  //-------------------//
  // define controller //
  //-------------------//
  angular.module('main').controller('indexController', IndexController);

  function IndexController($scope, messageService) {

    //scope variables
    $scope.message = messageService.getMessage;     //1
    $scope.ms = messageService;                     //2
    $scope.varMessage = messageService.varMessage;  //3
    $scope.varObject = messageService.varObject;    //4

    //scope functions
    $scope.updateMessageOne = UpdateMessageOne;
    $scope.updateMessageTwo = UpdateMessageTwo;

    //private controller functions
    function UpdateMessageOne() {

      messageService.setMessage('ONE!');

    }

    function UpdateMessageTwo() {

      messageService.setMessage('TWO!');

    }

  }

  //----------------------//
  // define directive one //
  //----------------------//
  angular.module('main').directive('messageDirective', MessageDirective);

  function MessageDirective() {

    //Return Directive Definition Object or "DDO"
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      templateUrl : 'message.tmpl.html'
    };

  }

  //----------------//
  // define service //
  //----------------//
  angular.module('main').service('messageService', MessageService);

  function MessageService(){

    //private variables
    var privateMessage = 'Initial Message';

    var privateObj = {
      message : 'Initial Message'
    }

    //service methods
    function SetMessage(newMessage){
      privateMessage = newMessage;
      privateObj.message = newMessage;
    }

    function GetMessage(){
      return privateMessage;
    }

    //return service definition
    return {
      setMessage : SetMessage,
      getMessage : GetMessage,
      varMessage : privateMessage,
      varObject : privateObj
    }

  }

})();
```

Directive Template HTML :

```
<div>
  Case 1 : {{message()}}
</div>
<div>
  Case 2 : {{ms.getMessage()}}
</div>
<div>
  Case 3 : {{varMessage}}
</div>
<div>
  Case 4 : {{varObject.message}}
</div>
```

Index Page HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.17" data-semver="1.3.17" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="indexController">

    <message-directive></message-directive>

    <button ng-click="updateMessageOne()">Update Message One</button>
    <button ng-click="updateMessageTwo()">Update Message Two</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code I would say YES, Case 3 will not get update. And the reason because when you **return the service definition object** and angular inject it to your controller. **messageService** will be the same object as you return it. to clear what i mean make the following changes:

update **UpdateMessageOne** function like below

```
function UpdateMessageOne() {
  console.log(messageService);
  messageService.setMessage('ONE!');
  console.log(messageService);
}
```

Now click the button and take a look at the console. You will find that the object is the same, and that of course normal. Because even if you updated the private variable the, **messageService** object is the same as when angular injected it.

So I'm not aware of any method that let you achieve what you want. But what you could do now is just use the **GetMessage** function like what you did with the others.